# Using estimation theorem to show integrals are zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I use the Estimation theorem to show the last two integrals on the right equal zero?
\begin{equation}
\int_{-R}^{R} e^{-\pi x z^{2}}dz= \int_{-R+i \frac{m}{x}}^{R + i \frac{m}{x}} e^{-\pi x z^{2}}dz + \int_{R + i \frac{m}{x}}^{R} e^{-\pi x z^{2}}dz + \int_{-R}^{-R + i \frac{m}{x}} e^{-\pi x z^{2}}dz 
\end{equation}

Should I take their absolute values, and show they have length $\frac{m}{x}$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They most likely aren't zero, but they tend to $0$ as $R\to +\infty$. Yes, take absolute values and note the length of the line segment is a finite constant (independent of $R$, that is).